# Suggestion to use 'bash' as syntax highlighting for text processing related tags

Tags: feature-request, formatting, syntax-highlighting

I recently came to know that we can use

```
<!-- language-all: bash -->
```

or

```
<!-- language: bash -->
```

for manually adding syntax highlighting. It is also mentioned in: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

I feel question using tags like `text-processing`, `sed`, `awk`, `grep`, etc but not `bash` could use syntax highlighting by default, instead of manual addition

Note: It need not be `bash` as such, anything suitable

Here's an example without syntax highlighting and one with `bash` syntax added

[image: with and without syntax highlighting example]

Comment: What syntax though? Mods can associate language styles to tags, but which one would we use for `text-processing`? How can we know what tool an answer would use? And what highlighting would make sense for `sed`? C can work for `awk` but what would make sense for `grep`?

Comment: @terdon I've added a snapshot.. it is more of command line syntax than language syntax..

Comment: Try it with `grep '#' file` though. Or `grep foo | perl -pe ...` etc which breaks both of them. It's kinda tricky to get right.

Comment: agree, it will not work good for all cases.. but that case already happens when `bash` is also tagged for those questions that have answers given with `sed/grep/awk/etc`.. if adding code block had usage like triple backtick plus language name (like used in github) it would be easier to simply add/change language.. anyway just thought this would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your trivial examples, syntax highlighting looks mildly good because they have short strings in them highlighted as such. But for most text *I* have seen, blanket-wrapping all awk or sed code (especially those that are even mildly complex) as a string is useless. It might as well not be highlighted at all.

Not only that, most of the actual text given as examples for processing have no meaningful application of bash syntax highlighting at all. In many cases, they just simply highlight random words and add noise to the text, making a visual parsing of it *harder*.

So, if highlighting was applied to the entire post because of a tag, at best they're mostly useless, at worst they're actively harming readability. I'd rather not have any syntax highlighting applied of these by default. If you need to highlight a command, highlight it using `<!-- language: ... -->`.

By the way, `awk` code can be syntax highlighted as awk, but not if it's wrapped in quotes:

```
<!-- language: lang-awk -->

    BEGIN {
       if ($0 ~ /foo/)
           print "foo"
    }
```

> [image]

So, if anything, [awk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awk) should be highlighted with that.

Comment: here's a Q&A regarding the noise you speak of  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409026/trim-tailing-and-add-it-leading-for-numbers-in-shell ... so perhaps we need a way to disable syntax highlighting for these..